# Creating several ways of referencing for just one type of label

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate, enumitem, cleveref, zref

I want to create a `statement` enumeration environment together with a referencing mechanism such that the code

```
\section{A section}
\begin{theorem}
    \begin{statement}
        \item Test \label{Test1}
        \item Test \label{Test2}
    \end{statement}
\end{theorem}
\begin{lemma}
    \begin{statement}
        \item Test \label{Test3}
        \item Test \label{Test4}
        \item Test \label{Test5}
    \end{statement}
\end{lemma}

\reference{Test1},

\referenceWithTheorem{Test2},

\labelreference{Test3},

\labelreferenceWithTheorem{Test4}

\referenceWithTheorem{Test5}
```

produces the following output with appropriate hyperlinks:

[image]

The following is important to me:

1. I can use the same environment `statement` for within `theorem` and `lemma`.
2. If I use `\referenceWithTheorem` or `\labelreferenceWithTheorem`, then precisely `<section>.<theorem> <statement>` becomes a hyperlink pointing to that statement.
3. The mechanism determines whether a statement is placed within a `theorem` or a `lemma`.

I will be very grateful if someone could provide help.

**Appendix:** Here is the code I used to produce the screenshot:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\begin{document}
    \section{A section}
    \begin{theorem}
        \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
            \item Test \label{Test1}
            \item Test \label{Test2}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{lemma}
        \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
            \item Test \label{Test3}
            \item Test \label{Test4}
            \item Test \label{Test5}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{lemma}

    Statement~\hyperref[Test1]{(i)},

    Theorem~\hyperref[Test2]{1.1 (ii)},

    \hyperref[Test3]{(i)},

    \hyperref[Test4]{1.2 (ii)},

    Lemma~\hyperref[Test5]{1.2 (iii)}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: `\upshape`, like `\slshape` and `\bfseries`, does not take an argument.

Comment: @Mico Thank you for the suggestion. So rather remove the curly braces after `\upshape` or rather replace `\upshape` by `\textup` ?

Comment: Indeed. The only meaningful difference is that `{\upshape ...}` allows paragraph breaks inside the curly braces, whereas `\textup{...}` does not.

Comment: @Mico `\textup` also handles italic correction

Comment: the standard way to do this would be to simply `\label` the theorem a well as the item and then use `\ref{item}` or `\ref{theorem}\ref{item}` depending which output you want.

Comment: @Mico presumably `\textup` is used in an italic context or why use it at all?  compare `\documentclass{article}

\showoutput
\begin{document}

\itshape

 f \textup{AAA} f

 f {\upshape AAA} f
\end{document}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Aaah, I'd completely overlooked that there may be a need to apply an italic correction at the *start* of an upright-letters block of text! I've deleted my earlier comment.

Comment: @Mico probably almost everyone overlooks that, which was one reason we made `\text...` commands do automatic italic correction when they were added to 2e :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What I don't like about your suggestion is that it does not make "1.1 (ii)" a single hyperlink pointing to that item.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is another possible solution.

I'm using the `cleveref` package, which defines macros that automatically format references. With this package, `\Cref{<some section>}` will produce "Section ⟨number⟩" and, if you are using amsthm, `\Cref{<some theorem>}` will produce "⟨theorem type⟩ ⟨number⟩".

I've made some modifications that allow you to reference items in the `statement` environment (and their names) in two ways.

- I'm using the package `enumitem` (which you also appear to use) to define the `statement` environment and I've set it up so that the label that is written to the aux file is actually of the form `\@twolabels{(i)}{1.1~(i)}`.
- I've defined `\@twolabels` as `\@firstoftwo`, so that `\@twolabels{(i)}{1.1~(i)}` expands to `(i)`. Thus, when you expand `\ref{Test<n>}` the output will be `(i)`.
- When you call `\refWithTheorem{Test<n>}`, `\@twolabels` is temporarily redefined to `\@secondoftwo`, after which `\ref{Test<n>}` is called. You will thus see the second part of the label, which contains the number of the surrounding theorem.
- At the start of the `statement` environment, I tell cleveref that the type corresponding to the `statementi` counter is `\@twolabels{statementi}{<the type of the surrounding environment>}`.
- The macro `\CrefWithTheorem` is defined as `\refWithTheorem`: it redefines `\@twolabels` to `\@secondoftwo` and then calls `\Cref`.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem} %% For \newlist
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref} %% For \Cref,\cref. You may or may not want to add [capitalize]

%% Defining the statement environment
\newlist{statement}{enumerate}{1}
%% Set ref to a pair consisting of the statement label and the combined label, with \@twolabels in front
\setlist[statement]{label=(\roman*),ref=\doublelabel{(\roman*)},before=\setcrefdoublealias}
%% Teaching cleveref about the name of this environment
\crefname{statementi}{statement}{statements} %% arguments are: name of counter, singular name, plural name

\makeatletter
%% \doublelabel defines a label of the form \@twolabels{<current>}{<previous>~<current>}
\newcommand*\doublelabel[1]{\protect\@twolabels{#1}{\@currentlabel~#1}}
%% \@twolabels causes the first label to be shown by default
%% It can be redefined to \@secondoftwo to retrieve the other label
\let\@twolabels\@firstoftwo

%% Telling cleveref that statementi is an alias for either itself or for the surrounding environment
%% (Which it is depends on how \@twolabels is defined)
\def\setcrefdoublealias{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup%
    \noexpand\crefalias{statementi}{%
      \noexpand\protect\noexpand\@twolabels%
        {statementi}{\expandafter\@extractcounterfromcreflabel\cref@currentlabel\end@extractcounterfromcreflabel}%
    }%
  }\x%
}
%% Extracts the environment name from \cref@currentlabel (which is of the form "[<counter name>]<other stuff>")
\def\@extractcounterfromcreflabel[#1]#2\end@extractcounterfromcreflabel{#1}

%% For defining WithTheorem versions of ref, cref, etc.
\newcommand*\versionWithTheorem[1]{\@ifstar{\versionWithTheorem@aux{#1*}}{\versionWithTheorem@aux{#1}}}
\newcommand*\versionWithTheorem@aux[2]{\begingroup\let\@twolabels\@secondoftwo#1{#2}\endgroup}
\makeatother

% % Versions of \ref and \Cref that include the surrounding environment name/label
\DeclareRobustCommand*\refWithTheorem{\versionWithTheorem\ref}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\CrefWithTheorem{\versionWithTheorem\Cref}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\crefWithTheorem{\versionWithTheorem\cref}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\nameCrefWithTheorem{\versionWithTheorem\nameCref}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\namecrefWithTheorem{\versionWithTheorem\namecref}

%% Theorem definitions
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\begin{theorem}
        \begin{statement}
        \item Test \label{Test1} 
        \item Test \label{Test2}
    \end{statement}
\end{theorem}
\begin{lemma}
    \begin{statement}
        \item Test \label{Test3}
        \item Test \label{Test4}
        \item Test \label{Test5}
    \end{statement}
\end{lemma}

\Cref{Test1}

\CrefWithTheorem{Test2}

\ref{Test3},

\refWithTheorem{Test4}

\CrefWithTheorem{Test5}

%% Support for referencing multiple labels at once
%% To also capitalise "lemma", use "\usepackage[capitalize]{cref}" above
Bonus (plural): \CrefWithTheorem{Test1,Test5,Test2}

%% Support for starred versions
Bonus (unlinked): \CrefWithTheorem*{Test4}

\end{document}
```

And here is the output:

[image]

**Edit:** Fixed a silly bug, don't use the old version.

**Edit:** Apparently `\setlist` has a `before` key, which makes using `\AtBeginEnvironment` (and loading `etoolbox`) unnecessary.
Also added support for the starred (unlinked) versions of `\ref`, `\cref` and `\Cref`

**Edit:** Removed trailing `\makeatletter` (oops)

Comment: Thank you also for your great answer. Due to the bonuses and the presence of the general `cref` functionality which I do enjoy, I would like to give the bounty to you (although I feel really bad in view of the other great answer). I also managed to add some `babel` functionality to your code and all in all I am very happy with it :-)

Comment: You're welcome, and thank you for the bounty =).</lag>

Answer (score 4):

More sophisticated reference problems require more sophisticated tools for generation of cross-referencing information.

`zref` is such a powerful tool. It has the `property` features which allows for storing additional information.

I have defined 3 properties:

- `envname`, which stores the outer environment name, e.g. Theorem or Lemma
- `theorem` → stores the theorem number as output by `\thetheorem`
- `lemma` → similar to `theorem`, stores `\thelemma`.

The macros

- `\reference`
- `\referencewithTheorem`
- `\labelreference`
- `\labelreferencewithTheorem`

all extract the relevant information written by `\zlabel` and show the information as desired.

`\zlabel` is done automatically by using the `\crtprelabelhook`.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[user,counter,hyperref]{zref}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}


\usepackage{crossreftools}

\newlist{statement}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[statement,1]{label={(\roman*)}}


\makeatletter
\providecommand{\@lastouterenv}{}

\zref@newprop{envname}[-1]{\@lastouterenv}

\zref@newprop{Lemma}[-1]{\thelemma}
\zref@newprop{Theorem}[-1]{\thetheorem}


\zref@addprops{main}{envname,Lemma,Theorem}


\renewcommand{\crtprelabelhook}[1]{%
  \zlabel{#1}%
}

\AtBeginEnvironment{theorem}{\renewcommand{\@lastouterenv}{Theorem}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{lemma}{\renewcommand{\@lastouterenv}{Lemma}}



\newcommand{\reference}[1]{%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{}{%
    Statement \hyperlink{\zref@extract{#1}{anchor}}{\zref@extract{#1}{default}}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\labelreference}[1]{%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{}{%
    \hyperlink{\zref@extract{#1}{anchor}}{\zref@extract{#1}{default}}%
  }%
}


\newcommand{\referencewithTheorem}[1]{%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{%
  }{%
    \zref@extract{#1}{envname}~\hyperlink{\zref@extract{#1}{anchor}}{\zref@extract{#1}{\zref@extract{#1}{envname}} \zref@extract{#1}{default}}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\labelreferencewithTheorem}[1]{%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{%
  }{%
    \hyperlink{\zref@extract{#1}{anchor}}{\zref@extract{#1}{\zref@extract{#1}{envname}} \zref@extract{#1}{default}}%
  }%
}


\makeatother


\begin{document}
    \section{A section}
    \begin{theorem}
        \begin{statement}
            \item Test \label{Test1}
            \item Test \label{Test2}
        \end{statement}
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{lemma}
        \begin{statement}
            \item Test \label{Test3}
            \item Test \label{Test4}
            \item Test \label{Test5}
        \end{statement}
    \end{lemma}

    \reference{Test1}%

    \referencewithTheorem{Test1}

    \labelreference{Test3},

    \labelreferencewithTheorem{Test4}

    \referencewithTheorem{Test5}




\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution works perfectly fine and also you managed to make me understand the `zref` package a little bit better (which the documentation could not manage, due to lack of examples). I am also glad to have found out about the`crossreftools` package by you. I am looking forward to `v.1.0` :-)